# Calling onkeyup function only once

Tags: javascript

I've written a sample HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate() {
alert(document.getElementById('newpass').value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="newpass" onkeyup="validate();" />
</body>
</html>
```

But in cases like when I press backspace, the function is getting called multiple times.
How do I make it to execute only once ?

All i want to do is to get the current value of a input box on an event, currently onkeypress is not giving the current one, but the previous one. onkeyup gives current but is executing many times.

Comment: It it the other way around... `keypup` fires once, while `keypress` fires multiple times.

Comment: Maybe `onchange` might work better in this case?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to get the current value of your input field as someone is typing, but want to ignore if they use backspace:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(that,e){
  var eventObject = window.event? event : e;
  var keyCode = eventObject.charCode? eventObject.charCode : eventObject.keyCode;
  if (keyCode != 8) {
    alert(that.value);
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="newpass" onkeyup="validate(this,event);" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I said that in my answer.. Wondering why create a new answer with nothing to add.

Comment: because I had the post an answer page open and was posting at the same time as you, but was slower because I was verifying my code... p.s. re: "nothing to add" your code isn't cross-browser compatible, compare our code.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW There is a 3-minute gap between your answers, which is a small enough time interval to assume that this answer was probably in the process of being written at the time you posted yours.

Comment: Hmm so window.event and event.which is not enough? Edit: lol you are the one who needs to 'chillax'  I'm just asking to see why (window.event? event : e) makes it more cross-browser compatible.  nice pic btw lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to get the value when the user is done typing then use `onchange` instead of on key up

Note: 
`onkeyup` is working as it should. If you release the key it gets called once. If you hold on backspace then release then it only gets called once.

`onkeypress` does not get the value because the event is kicked before the value gets stored.

Another option is to ignore backspace

```
function validate(event) {
    var keynum;
    if (window.event) {
       keynum = window.event.keyCode;
    } else if (event.which) {
       keynum = event.which;
    }

    if (keynum == 8) { // backspace 
      return;
    }
    alert(document.getElementById('newpass').value);
}
```

Or you can check the previous key, if it's the same then ignore it

```
var previousKey;
function validate(event) {
    var keynum;
    if (window.event) {
       keynum = window.event.keyCode;
    } else if (event.which) {
       keynum = event.which;
    }

    if (keynum == previousKey) { // backspace 
      return;
    }

    previousKey = keynum;

    alert(document.getElementById('newpass').value);
}
```

Or if its a backspace again ignore